# Safari / Webkit CSS scroll-snap bug?

Tags: css, scroll, safari, cross-browser, webkit

I can't seem to make scroll-snap work properly on Safari (either desktop or iOS).

The bug (?) happens when an item's content is taller than the viewport, in which case Safari snap-scrolls right away to the next item making it impossible to read the contents of an item with a long text. This is not the case on Chrome, Firefox or Opera where it's possible to scroll throughout any long snapping section and the snapping to the start of the next item will only occur at the bottom of that long item (making it possible to be read).

Here is a Demo: https://codepen.io/xfze/pen/YzWXdQv

relevant code used:

```
ul {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
li {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

as anyone ever got around this and got Safari behaving as Chrome/Firefox/Opera?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use instead of mandatory, proximity for safari. The spec talks about this possible problem [w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scroll-snap-1/#valdef-scroll-snap-type-mandatory)

Comment: I tried but it's quite cumbersome compared to the "normal mandatory", I fount it worse than having to "freeze scroll" long sections.

Comment: It could be kinda janky but maybe you can add the scroll snap to the div when the user scrolled past a certain point. It cannot be done in pure css and isn't too elegant but maybe it helps?

Comment: I have a CSS fix (not great but for now works): I set the snap-align of the long sections when on Safari as center.

Answer (score 3):

Actualy safari made it correctly while the other are just making kind of `proximity`.

So even if I understood you don't like proximity, the way you are expecting to be `mandatory` do not make sens, let me explain.

`mandatory` is trying to fix view always to the the `start` of the `child` when you set `scroll-snap-align: start;` that means that child height must be `max-height: 100vh;` to have a right effect.

Because if you don't then the user won't ever be able to read the bottom of the `li`, try to make it with your demo, you will see, that it goes straight up to the next `li` when it is entering to the screen.

So based on what you wish, I would suggest you set:

- Either you set `proximity`
- Either you set `li{ max-height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto; }` and set the content into a `div`. But really hard to manage for user.
- Either you use jQuery old way as below demo

Have a look to: [CSS TRICKS SCROLL SNAP](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/#scroll-snap-type-mandatory-vs-proximity)

DEMO with pure jQuery:

```js
var items = $(".item");
var animating = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    if (!animating) {
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
          var count = 0;
          items.each(function(key, value) {
            /** Adjust the 200 value to make scroll larger than 200px before and after the top of the item **/
           /** You can even make the value dynamic depending on screen by getting the viewport height and apply a percentage to it. ie: $( window ).height() * .8 ; **/
            if (($(window).scrollTop() > ($(value).offset().top - 200)
            && ($(window).scrollTop() - $(value).offset().top) < 200)
            || ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(value).offset().top + 200)
            && ($(window).scrollTop() - $(value).offset().top) < 200)) {
              animating = true;
              $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(value).offset().top }, 250);
              setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 300);
              return false;
            }
          });
        }, 200));
    }
});
```

```css
li {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul>
        <li class="item"><div>Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br /></div></li>
        <li class="item"><div>fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br /></div></li>
  
  <li class="item"><div>Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br /></div></li>
        <li><div>fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br /></div></li>
  
  <li><div>Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br /></div></li>
        <li class="item"><div>fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br /></div></li>
  
  <li class="item"><div>Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br />Lorem, ipsum dolor.<br /></div></li>
        <li class="item"><div>fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br />fugit cenas bla bla<br /></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would argue safari's implementation of mandatory is inferior. I do expect content to be mandatory snapped to the start of each section when scrolling, UNLESS that section is bigger than the viewport in which case the snapping will only occur when the end of this section is reached (which is the behaviour of Chrome, etc..).

Comment: What I get with proximity is that the snapping doesn't occur at the end of any section (bigger or smaller than the view), the snapping only happens after a big chunk of the next section is already scrolled through the screen at which point it snaps to its start (which is not what I intend at all, for example I have titles at the start of which section which are expected to snap to top of the screen and not be displayed until the middle and then be snapped to top...).

Comment: as for your second solution it's better than my current one but still doesn't allow safari to replicate exactly the behavior of Chrome/FF/etc... With max-height/overflow-y set on the section to be scrolled safari does allow bigger sections to be scrolled until the end (and be read by the user!) and only then it snaps to the start of the next (and it doesn't wait for the middle of the next section to snap as proximity would do, it snaps to the start of section B when one reaches the end of section A which is precisely what we want). Two differences remain:

Comment: 1. When scrolling back up from section B it scrolls back to the end of A instead of the start of A.
2. It adds scroll bars (not very pretty on the middle of a webpage)

Both problems propagate to chrome so I needed to use your fix only when detected browser isSafari. (on some sections I still use my previous snap-align: center hack, otherwise I would get a huge blank scroll, but that's probably related to some code fixing I need to do anyway on those sections)

Comment: @xfze please have look to the solution it is the old way. but should work fine on every browser

Comment: I've tried your snippet on both chrome and safari and what happens is that it only snaps to the next section when it's almost already at the top (similar to regular proximity but it has to be even closer to the edge to snap, in fact if you don't scroll slowly you don't even notice the snap). Is it rendering differently on your browser?

Comment: @xfze yes but as I said you in js code, you can manage the distance you wish by modifying the value of 200 or making it dynamicly with `You can even make the value dynamic depending on screen by getting the viewport height and apply a percentage to it. ie: $( window ).height() * .8 ;` Because now it just goes but when it is at 200px from the section but you can make it from 400px or how ever you wish with dynamic way

Comment: yeah it's definitely possible to have JS make it dynamic and snap the start of the next section to the top of the screen only when the bottom of the previous section has been reached. I just preferred a CSS fix because my site has already too much JS going on and also wanted to make sure there wasn't a CSS way to make safari behave "properly" before opening a bug. Anyway thanks for your help, you definitely deserve the bounty ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry that there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `-webkit?`

Some `-webkit-scroll-snap` examples for Safari: https://webkit.org/demos/scroll-snap/index.html

Perhaps:

```
div {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

li {
    -webkit-scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work as one can see on the codepen demo provided. the problem is not that there is no mandatory scroll-snap, it works even without the -webkit but it just doesn't handle well long sections (and the other browsers do)

Comment: @xfze Gotcha--I'm not sure then whether there's a good CSS solution...as someone else mentioned, you could try a less-elegant Javascript solution and `scrollTop`, although animation would then be trickier.