# Webkit Scroll Snap Bug?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317214/safari-webkit-css-scroll-snap-bug) question, but it seems to address a different issue.

In my case, scroll snapping doesn't always work together with anchor links (or the `scrollIntoView` method) *only* when the scroll box is `html` (and not `body` or `main` or some other container).  I have an iPhone XR with iOS 16.

[Here](https://qq04s3.csb.app/) is a CodeSandbox to easily test on the phone.  (I didn't include a code snippet in the post, as this is best to be experienced full screen, on the phone.)

When I make another container the scroll box, scrolling 'away' the address bar in Safari doesn't work anymore, and since I like this feature, I'd prefer to have `html` being my scroll box.

Is this really a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, following some of the tips given here helped me figure this out: https://ishwar-rimal.medium.com/fixing-that-address-bar-issue-in-mobile-browsers-once-and-for-all-8c283fc88e56

Key takeaways, I think:

1. `overflow: hidden` on `html`
2. `overflow-y: scroll` on `body`; this is also where you set the 100% height (not on html)
3. Set all of your scroll snap stuff on `body`

Comment: Just kidding, I am an idiot - this doesn't actually solve this; the address bar now doesn't collapse. Kill me

Comment: Haha don't worry.  I already forgot about this question because I found a solution.  It's a bit hacky, but I disable scroll snap before I request `scrollIntoView`, then enable it 1 second later or so via `setTimeout`...